# Home screen bumped down by nothing

Tags: tiles

On my Nokia Lumia 1020, I've noticed the following:

The topmost tiles of the home screen always default to a position a little bit down from the top of the screen. It appears to be the height of a toast notification, not just the height of the clock, etc. This is frustrating because the tiles are designed to fit on the full screen and when they default to this position there is a big unnecessary black bar at the top and the bottom row of tiles gets cut off, rather than being fully visible as intended. Looking around, it seems that people with other Windows phones are having the same experience:

[image]  [image]
[image]

Has anyone else noticed this? Is there a fix or workaround?

Comment: Huh.  Mine does the same.  I'd never noticed it till now.  Thanks a lot, now it's going to bug me from now on.  :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a design decision made by the Windows Phone team at Microsoft and the home screen has been this way since Windows Phone 7 up to Windows Phone 8 GDR 3 (or Update 3).

> Has anyone else noticed this?

You bet. There are very active discussions about this taking place on:

1. [WPCentral: Screen blank space at the top](http://forums.wpcentral.com/htc-8x/206114-screen-blank-space-top.html)
2. [Windows Phone User Voice: Start Screen Improvement - Remove excess blank/black space from the top of the Start Screen](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3893784-start-screen-improvement-remove-excess-blank-bla)

In the case of the latter, you can add your vote(s) to the issue.

> Is there a fix or workaround?

No workaround at this time. Windows Phone 8 is constantly being updated though so having an option to adjust that empty space is always a (in my opinion, unlikely) possibility.

---

**Edit: More research on whether this can be done by building an app**

I wanted to find out if there were any API's out there that might allow me to build an app to eliminate the blank space. Since Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 share a lot of their source code, I wanted to find out if there were any Windows 8 API's out there that would allow me to change the positioning of tiles.

[Turns out I am not the only one who has been thinking along these lines...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994978/how-to-place-a-tile-on-the-windows-8-start-screen-programmatically)

What it boils down to is that there are no API's that might allow developers to do such a thing (yet) and any other way of hacking this will probably not be approved for the Marketplace anyway!

Comment: I appreciate this thoughtful, thorough answer, even if it's not what I wanted to hear. I've added my votes to the pool, but my hopes are not high since the suggestion is 242nd on the list and there are plenty of people who don't notice it, or don't care, or actually think it's a feature.

Comment: Yes, rightly so. I wouldn't pin my hopes of Microsoft fixing this. The other avenue to consider is maybe the phone manufacturer like Nokia/Samsung doing something OR the phone carrier like AT & T or T-Mobile OR lastly someone making an app.

Comment: I know it seems like a little thing, but I would actually pay good money for an app that does nothing but fix this.

Comment: I'm going to give it a go :)

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung I have edited my answer with more detail

Comment: I see, thank you. That's unfortunate, but also pretty much what I expected.